# SDL2: Slow window clean and update

Tags: c++, sdl-2, frame-rate

I found out that my program - which only draw two pictures on the screen  - runs at 200FPS. 200FPS is really low number at this point of development! It does not matter if I remove all textures and other data.

The slow part of code are *SDL_RenderPresent* and *SDL_RenderClear*. Without them, the program runs at about 300K FPS. Could you tell me where could be the problem?

**Window and Renderer**

```
_window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, 0 );

if ( _window == NULL ) {
    std::cout << "CreateWindow problem: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
}

_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( _window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );

if ( _renderer == NULL ) {
    std::cout << "CreateRenderer problem: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
}
```

Acording to *SDL_RendererInfo* only two flags are used - SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED and SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE.

Comment: RenderPresent render your frames to be on the screen and RenderClear clear the screen to draw a new frame, you should post your main loop too, because your performance issues is in there and I don't think that RenderPresent and RenderClear are your problem, because in my code, the rendering took between 2 and 5 ms, with a lot of drawing... at 5 ms it means 250fps

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/fHdVDEsb. FPS is just about 200.

Comment: What function are you using to get your ticks with Timer class, SDL_GetTicks() ?

Comment: Yes, it is similar to [Lazyfoo Timer](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson12/index.php). I do not think  that my calculation is the problem. I am using Debian with self-build SDL2. Is it not necessary to allow HW rendering in SDL2 configure?

Comment: I'm just asking, because I had trouble on Ubuntu with clock_t() that take like 2 sec to call and my games was unplayable so I switched to std::chrono, I'll take a look at LazyFoo Timer because your rendering code seems ok.

Comment: I took a look at SDL_GetTicks() implementation for Unix and its using clock_gettime() that function seems to take a lot of CPU Usage on the last version of Debian/Ubuntu, other people got that problem. You should use std::chrono to time your frame rendering. Take a look at : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: I will test chrono as soon as posible. But I don't think SDL_GetTicks() is the problem. After removing of RenderClear and RenderPresent FPS is around 300 000. In additional `std::cout << SDL_GetTicks() << " " << SDL_GetTicks() << std::endl;` prints two same numbers...

Comment: The problem seems to be somewhere in drivers or something like this. In Windows, program runs around 4000FPS. Thank you for help!